# What of Reinhold Niebuhr clashes 'with modern racial sensibilities'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [[35% down the page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/charity/against_1.shtml):] One example given by Niebuhr (who was writing in 1930s USA) was the way charitable help for black education didn't deal with the roots of the problem. **His language is not in line with modern racial sensibilities**, but the point is still of value.
>
> > The Negro schools, conducted under the auspices of white philanthropy, encourage individual Negroes to higher forms of self-realisation; but they do not make a frontal attack upon the social injustices from which the Negro suffers.
>
> Reinhold Niebuhr, Moral Man and Immoral Society, 1932

Please elucidate what linguistic problems conflict with **modern racial sensibilities**? Niebuhr raises awareness of and reports problems facing the 'Negro', so 'Negro' isn't used scornfully or derisively?

Comment: Suppose it would have been normal to call coloured people "garbage" back in the 30's. Can you understand that such language would offend people today, and thus "clash with modern racial sensibilities", in other words, people would get upset if you used it? Now for the important missing piece of information: the word "negro" has nowadays as bad a connotation as calling people "garbage".

Comment: @oerkelens *Negro* actually replaced *colored people* as the acceptable term to use. It wasn't till Malcom X decided that *Negro* had too many associations with slavery that the term was replaced with another (*black*), a term that at the time was considered objectionable.

Comment: Sorry, read "black" or any other preferred term where I used anything that may cause offence :) I'm actually not interested enough in skin colour to keep fully up to date with the current acceptable terms in all possible settings :)

Comment: Some people might be uncomfortable with the word ***Negro*** itself, but I think the main problem with the extract is its use of the definite article in ***the** Negro*. This very much has the effect of setting "the archetypal" Negro apart from other people in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, blacks or African Americans are not generally referred to as "Negroes." The reasons why take as far afield from linguistics into sociological studies and history, including the history of that word *among blacks.*

I suspose "modern racial sensibilities" might also have difficulty with any notion that the betterment of African Americans in American society comes under "the auspices of white philanthropy." But I can only conjecture, and this really is not a linguistic issue but a socio-cultural or interracial one.

Edit: I will add that since historical linguistics is a part of linguistics, a look at the historical use of the word *Negro* is within the parameters of this website, especially when others are already referring to the word in ahistorical terms

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negro) does an all right job of stressing that *Negro* was for decades the widely accepted term among black leaders including MLK, who used it with aplomb in his "I have a dream" speech.

In addition, *Negro* was for decades  considered acceptable as a self-referent wheras *black* was considered objectionable. A flip-flop in "sensibilities" occurred in the turbulent years of the Civil Rights movement, and *black* came to replace *Negro*, although even today *Negro* is used by some African Americans.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I was enlightened by the 'socio-cultural or interracial one'! I hadn't divined that!

Answer (score 0):

'Negro' has all sorts of connotations - it was used in scientific and academic circles quite condescendingly as a name for the 'species' of black people. Note the reference to 'the Negro', like you or I would say 'the ape' or 'the dog' or 'the toaster'. I'd say it it distinguishes black people from humans. It's also the parent word of a rather foul, racially-charged epithet which I'd rather not repeat, and inextricably associated with a period in African-American history which is still fresh and sore.

For those reasons, although it was quite common back in the days when that paper was written, you would get some rather angry responses if you used it in a modern context.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively. Please don’t mind the selection; the other had updated. I don't understand the downvotes though.